# People view showing some users multiple times and others not at all

Tags: views, users, 9

I'm seeing some weird behavior in the build-in People view and I'm going to try to explain it.

There are 168 users in my site. If I change the view to show them all (and not paginate), it shows them all fine. If I revert to default pagination (50 per page), it still shows a total of 168 records across 4 pages, but some users are duplicated and others left out.

In trying to understand what is happening, I took the query and ran it directly on my database ...

```
SELECT users_field_data.uid
FROM users_field_data users_field_data
WHERE (users_field_data.default_langcode = '1') AND (users_field_data.uid != '0')
ORDER BY users_field_data.created DESC
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Changing the offset to 50, 100, 150 simulates pushing the next page button. When I run these queries, some uids (e.g. uid = 101) show up multiple times and some are not present at all.

If I take out the `LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0` so that it returns all 168 rows at once, this does not happen. Similarly, if I change the sort to `ORDER BY users_field_data.created DESC`, this does not happen even if I add the pagination back in.

I copied all the results to Excel and sorted them and below is what I end up with - notice how 101 is present 3 times in the first column but not the second and 45 is not even in the first column. Anyone have any idea why this is happening? I'm at a complete loss.

Thanks!

| Paginated | Not Paginated |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 12 | 12 |
| 47 | 45 |
| 48 | 46 |
| 49 | 47 |
| 51 | 48 |
| 52 | 49 |
| 53 | 50 |
| 54 | 51 |
| 55 | 52 |
| 55 | 53 |
| 56 | 54 |
| 56 | 55 |
| 57 | 56 |
| 57 | 57 |
| 60 | 58 |
| 62 | 59 |
| 63 | 60 |
| 64 | 61 |
| 65 | 62 |
| 66 | 63 |
| 66 | 64 |
| 67 | 65 |
| 67 | 66 |
| 68 | 67 |
| 69 | 68 |
| 70 | 69 |
| 71 | 70 |
| 72 | 71 |
| 73 | 72 |
| 86 | 73 |
| 87 | 74 |
| 87 | 75 |
| 88 | 76 |
| 88 | 77 |
| 89 | 78 |
| 89 | 79 |
| 90 | 80 |
| 90 | 81 |
| 90 | 82 |
| 91 | 83 |
| 91 | 84 |
| 91 | 85 |
| 92 | 86 |
| 92 | 87 |
| 92 | 88 |
| 93 | 89 |
| 93 | 90 |
| 93 | 91 |
| 94 | 92 |
| 94 | 93 |
| 95 | 94 |
| 95 | 95 |
| 96 | 96 |
| 96 | 97 |
| 96 | 98 |
| 97 | 99 |
| 97 | 100 |
| 97 | 101 |
| 98 | 102 |
| 98 | 103 |
| 98 | 104 |
| 99 | 106 |
| 99 | 107 |
| 99 | 108 |
| 100 | 109 |
| 100 | 110 |
| 100 | 111 |
| 101 | 112 |
| 101 | 113 |
| 101 | 114 |
| 102 | 115 |
| 102 | 116 |
| 102 | 117 |
| 103 | 121 |
| 103 | 122 |
| 103 | 123 |
| 104 | 125 |
| 104 | 126 |
| 104 | 127 |
| 106 | 128 |
| 106 | 129 |
| 114 | 130 |
| 115 | 131 |
| 116 | 132 |
| 117 | 133 |
| 121 | 134 |
| 122 | 135 |
| 123 | 136 |
| 125 | 137 |
| 126 | 138 |
| 127 | 139 |
| 128 | 140 |
| 129 | 141 |
| 130 | 142 |
| 148 | 148 |
| 149 | 149 |
| 153 | 153 |
| 270 | 270 |
| 272 | 272 |
| 273 | 273 |
| 274 | 274 |
| 285 | 285 |
| 286 | 286 |
| 287 | 287 |
| 288 | 288 |
| 292 | 292 |
| 299 | 299 |
| 300 | 300 |
| 301 | 301 |
| 302 | 302 |
| 303 | 303 |
| 304 | 304 |
| 305 | 305 |
| 307 | 307 |
| 315 | 315 |
| 316 | 316 |
| 324 | 324 |
| 339 | 339 |
| 351 | 351 |
| 353 | 353 |
| 356 | 356 |
| 357 | 357 |
| 358 | 358 |
| 362 | 362 |
| 363 | 363 |
| 364 | 364 |
| 365 | 365 |
| 366 | 366 |
| 367 | 367 |
| 379 | 379 |
| 380 | 380 |
| 381 | 381 |
| 382 | 382 |
| 384 | 384 |
| 421 | 421 |
| 424 | 424 |
| 425 | 425 |
| 426 | 426 |
| 427 | 427 |
| 433 | 433 |
| 436 | 436 |
| 438 | 438 |
| 439 | 439 |
| 440 | 440 |
| 441 | 441 |
| 442 | 442 |
| 443 | 443 |
| 444 | 444 |
| 445 | 445 |
| 446 | 446 |
| 448 | 448 |
| 449 | 449 |
| 450 | 450 |
| 451 | 451 |
| 452 | 452 |
| 453 | 453 |
| 454 | 454 |
| 455 | 455 |
| 456 | 456 |
| 458 | 458 |
| 459 | 459 |
| 460 | 460 |
| 461 | 461 |
| 462 | 462 |
| 463 | 463 |
| 464 | 464 |
| 465 | 465 |

If it helps, here is all the data for uid=101:

```
|101|en|en|bill.moody|[hashed pass]|[unique email]|America/New_York|0|1547769784|1579710354|1579706734|1579706734|1
```

And here is the data for one not showing up (uid=45):

```
|45|en|en|joyce.pelz|[hashed pass]|[unique email]|America/New_York|1|1547769784|1669957934|1681242515|1681241569|1
```

Comment: Sorry ... Drupal 9.5.7, Database Version 10.3.27-MariaDB

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on a plain Drupal 9 installation. The view on /admin/people does not show duplicates, even when I set the view to show 4 items per page from /admin/structure/views/view/user_admin_people.